# How to determine last merged branch in git?

Tags: git, bash, merge

I need to determine which was the last branch merged into master.

I have been searching around the git docs but I am still a bit lost. So far I have found the command (assuming master is my current branch)

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate
```

Which provides me an output like this

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate
*   12cfc6d (HEAD, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) Merge branch 'release/VCS_6.12.0-20150826' to master
|\  
| *   bef8908 (origin/release/VCS_6.12.0-20150826) Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/release/VCS_6.12.0-20150826' into release/VCS_6.12.0-20150826
| |\  
| | *   c61f97b Merge pull request #12 in COM/vcs from feature/SWAT-47-Loader-JMS to release/VCS_6.12.0-20150826
| | |\  
| | | *   33aefe6 (origin/feature/SWAT-47-Loader-JMS) [SWAT-47] Merge from release/VCS_6.12.0-20150826 branch
| | | |\  
| | | |/  
| | |/|   
| | * | 8f452b0 Revert pom.xml and fix formatting.
| | * | 128b347 Modified pom.xml by git hook. Command was mvn ci-versions:reset -DforceVersion=feature/VCS-4590_Migrate_translation_util_features
| | * | eaa9065 VCS-4590 - Migrate dev.vcs translation util to VCS production
| | | * 6fe1adc [SWAT-47] Move jmsProductUpdateListener bean to publishState-common-meta and properties config to appconfig.
| | | * ec8311f [SWAT-47] Revert the change of skipping role check for local testing
| | | * e545332 [SWAT-47] Fix checkstyle issues
| | | *   0df27b4 Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/feature/SWAT-47-Loader-JMS' into feature/SWAT-47-Loader-JMS
| | | |\  
| | | | * cb87d1b Play with JMS
| | | * | 5f55b97 [SWAT-47] Added jmsProductUpdateListener to publish JMS message to jmsProductUpdate topic instead of jmsCacheReset topic.
| | | * | 09f1bc9 [SWAT-47] Play with JMS
| | | |/
```

There you can see that the last branch merged was "origin/release/VCS_6.12.0-20150826".

Is there a simpler way to determine this with one (or several) bash commands?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
git log --first-parent --merges -1 --oneline
```

should do it.

Comment: I think this works for the case when a branch can be fast-forwarded - so that both branch heads match exactly.... however if there is a merge pull request committed as part of the merge, the merge target will have a single extra merge pr commit beyond the merge source and the refs won't match anymore.  Pulling that merge commit back into the source from the target will sync the two branches, and only then will this work as expected?  Have I understood that right?